# what will happen if i use DDR3 and DDR2 RAM simultaneously?

Tags: memory

What will happen if i use DDR3 and DDR2 RAM simultaneously on a single motherboard that suports both? Will the motherboard and Ram get damaged? Also, what will be the result of using DDR2 Ram in DDR3 slot and vice versa. Won't try such things though. Asking out of curiosity

Comment: Please post your motherboard make/model. It totally depends on whether it supports mixed mode, populating DDR2 and DDR3 memory modules simultaneously. I doubt it would fry your ram as I would hope the mobo manufacturer would implement safeguards against this.

Comment: Your computer [loses its mind](http://www.maximumpc.com/files/u58308/ComputerExplode.jpg).

Comment: I do not believe this can be done. If someone thinks it can work then please post that MB's make & model. I looked at two boards from two different manufacturers and both contained warnings similiar to this: "You can only install either DDR2 module(s) or DDR3 module(s) on the motherboard; otherwise, the system will not boot up."

Comment: @JoshK is that a real picture of the aftermath of installed mis-matched memory?

Comment: @CodeBlend No. I have seen it with the following caption (reproduced verbatim): _This is what happn when the soni battery go boom. It causes fire and computtttu goes in smoke. IT is bad thing. All batterio are affected._ 
(picture here)
_Tat is teh end results on an apple microsft dell idell pro editon._

Comment: DDR2 won't fit into a DDR3 DIMM slot, and DDR3 won't fit into a DDR2 DIMM slot. Here is a photo of DDR2 & DDR3 side by each: http://build-gaming-computer-guide.com/image-files/ddr3-vs-ddr2-ram.jpg. If the DIMM fits the slot the Mo-Bo will run it.

Answer (score 2):

Its Simple - You cant.

The motherboard will refuse to power on at best, or fry the ram at worst.

What mobo supports both anyway ?

Comment: Not true. While they are rare, I have seen µATX boards that support mixed mode memory pairing.

Comment: Frankly, I agree with c10k you can't do this. If you think you know of board which will use DDR2 & DDR3 simultaneously then please post the make and model number so this can be verified.

Comment: @irrationalJohn  Asus P5KC and MSI P35 Platinum Combo among others.  Both're P35 boards which had support for both ram types in the chipset.  They were never common since only a handful of upgraders would have any use for them.

Comment: The P5KC's specification says "Dual-channel DDR2 1066/800/667 MHz **or** DDR3 1333/1066/800". The manual says, "You can only install either DDR2 module(s) or DDR3 module(s) on the motherboard, otherwise, the system will not boot up." (Page 2-14)

Answer (score 0):

The slots are incompatible, so you can't put DDR2 Memory in a DDR3 Slot, or vice versa. If your MB support both, as some do, then you'll have to consult the MB Documentation to know if you can use both at the same time (most do, not all).

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend it, even if you have an uber special motherboard that will support mixed ram.

Comment: These MBs aren't all that rare, but most people will want to just stick with one type anyway.

Answer (score -4):

P5KC Asus motherboard has 6 ports (ram ports)    and I have two  DDR2 kingston 1GB  and DDR3 kingston 1333btz 2GB :)) and its working exelent ,

Comment: Page 2-14 of the manual specifically says, "You can only install either DDR2 module(s) or DDR3 module(s) on the motherboard, otherwise, the system will not boot up."